# Check if array contains at least one value from a string

Tags: php

Is it possible to check if an array contains at least one value from a string? The string is an outputted list (see below).

This is my array, let's call it `$data`

```
Array ( [0] => finance-accounting-banking [1] => fixed-term [2] => human-resources [3] => international [4] => logistics-supply-chain [5] => management [6] => marketing )
```

And this is my outputted list, let's call it `$types`.

```
fixed-term|marketing
```

I thought this might've worked but no such luck...

```
if (in_array($types, $data))
```

Comment: You should be able to split the list into individual terms and use in_array on each. Looks like you may be searching for "fixed-term|marketing" which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @ckimbrell Yep, exactly. I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `$types` variable will have the values separated by `|`, here is a code that doesn't use preg:

```
$data = array ( 0 => 'finance-accounting-banking', 1 => 'fixed-term', 2 => 'human-resources', 3 => 'international', 4 => 'logistics-supply-chain', 5 => 'management', 6 => 'marketing' );
$types = 'fixed-term|marketing';

if(count(array_intersect($data, explode('|', $types))) > 0){
    echo 'found';
}else{
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$types` is exactly in the format that you mentioned, you can do it simply by using `preg_grep()` function:

```
$atLeastOne = count(preg_grep('/' . $types . '/', $input)) != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pieces = explode('|',$types);
foreach ($pieces as $element) {
    if ( in_array($element,$data) ) {
        echo "found";
    }
}
```

Comment: `type 1 -- Call to undefined function array_in()`. [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Hint: break the loop once the value's found to avoid: 1- echoing `found` multiple times; 2- needles iterations;