# Check if string contains a value in 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and 1 string.
I'm trying to detect if a string contains at least one value stored in each array.

```
$array1 = array('night', 'morning', 'afternoon');
$array2 = array('robert','david','justin');
$string ='robert read a book this morning';
```

my code:

```
if (strstr($string, $array1) && strstr($string, $array2)){
    echo "Match found";}else{ echo "Not found";}
```

Is there a right way of doing things?

Comment: Does it get the right answer? Did you test it strenuously? Then you should be able to tell us if its right!!

Comment: Your current attempt should give you a warning/fatal error (depending on PHP version), because the second parameter to `strstr` can not be an array.

Comment: _"Is there a right way of doing things?"_ - loop over the first array, and check for each item individually. If you found a match, set a flag (and exit the loop), repeat process with the second array. Check if both of those flags are true afterwards ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if array contains at least one value from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384190/check-if-array-contains-at-least-one-value-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1 = ['night', 'morning', 'afternoon'];
$array2 = ['robert','david','justin'];
$string ='robert read a book this morning';
$array = explode(' ', $string);

if (! empty(array_intersect($array, $array1))
    || ! empty(array_intersect($array, $array1))
) {
    echo 'Match found';
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';
}
```

Comment: I think `||` should be `&&` as the spec says "at least one value stored in each array`

Comment: @RiggsFolly If you need to echo "Match found" when a string contains the word that is in two arrays, then yes.

Comment: Yes, thats what "at least one value stored in **each** array" means to me